# Text comes in wrong in Access form

Tags: ms-access

I have an inventory database. When I enter a description (24" Monitor) on a form it looks as it should. When I open another form with the description, it comes in as

`<div>24&quot, Monitor</div>`

Any ideas why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: set the Textbox `TextFormat` Property from `plaintext` to `Richtext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Inventory Database the Description field is set as Memo field.

If you try to get the values from memo field into a `plaintext` than you will get the text as `HTML` Format as above.

To avoid any confusion make sure what you would like to achieve. Either set the Textbox `TextFormat` Property from `plaintext` to `Richtext` or Change the datatype of the Description field from `longtext` (Richtext) to `longtext` (Plaintext) or change to `ShorT Text`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks

Comment: That's nice one!